# Selecionar um elemento na DOM que será carregado via JS

Tags: javascript

Quero fazer um mousehover em alguns elementos que serão carregados via JS. Como faço para selecionar um elemento que ainda não foi carregado?

Elemento a ser carregado através de um foreach e insertAdjacentHTML

```
export const renderMemoriaCard = () => {

var markupMemoriaOut = '';
memoriaMensal.forEach(el => {
    
    var markupContent = '';
    el.filmes.forEach(num => {
        markupContent += `
        <p class="memoria__film opensans-bold rosa-neon">
            ${num.titulo}
        </p>
        <p class="memoria__tec opensans-regular branco">${num.fichatec}</p>
        <p class="memoria__direcao opensans-regular branco">
            ${num.direcao}
        </p>
        `
    });

    markupMemoriaOut += `
    <a href="memoria/${el.id}.html" class="memoria__card"> 
    <div class="memoria__bg memoria__bg--${el.id}">&nbsp;</div>
        <p class="memoria__header bebas">
        <span class="memoria__sessao">${el.sessao}:</span> ${el.local}
        </p>
        <div class="memoria__content">
        ${markupContent}
        </div>
        <div class="memoria__footer">
        <div class="memoria__data bebas branco">
            ${el.data}
        </div>
        <div class="memoria__btn">
            <svg class="memoria__btn-icon">
            <use xlink:href="img/right-arrow.svg#Layer_1"></use>
            </svg>
        </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    `;
});

elements.memoria.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markupMemoriaOut);
```

}

Função para fazer o mouse hover adicionando algumas classes nos elementos depois de carregados:

```
const mouseHoverCard = () => {
    elements.memoriaContent.classList.toggle = '.memoria__content--hover';
    elements.memoriaBg.classList.toggle = '.memoria__bg--hover'
    elements.memoriaData.classList.toggle = '.memoria__data--hover';
}
```

lista de elementos selecionados:

```
memoriaContent: document.querySelector('.memoria__content'),
memoriaData: document.querySelector('.memoria__data'),
memoriaBg: document.querySelector('.memoria__bg')
```

Comment: Acho que faltam informações na sua pergunta. Como você determina quando de fato os elementos estarão na página (porque só se pode selecioná-los uma vez que eles já estejam no DOM). Uma opção é adicionar os _event listeners_ logo após a inserção desses elementos na página. Tente [edit] a pergunta para clarificar isso um pouco (se possível, inclua também o código que realiza essa inserção). :-)

Comment: O código que realiza a inserção na página é um forEach com insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Eles estão em string, ou seja não são elementos HTML ainda, o que pode fazer é deixar de usar insertAdjacentHTML  e innerHTML e passar a usar document.createElement para gerar um a um os elementos e antes mesmo de adicionar ao corpo da página você já os terá selecionados, caso isso seja muito complicado você pode usar DocumentFragment e criar um DIV dentro dele, nesse DIV use o insertAdjacentHTML com sua string, então no fragmento você poderá usar querySelector para obter os elementos e depois você poderá adicionar o fragmento diretamente ao elements.memoria com appendChild ...

Comment: ... claro que vai ficar um DIV como elemento pai, mas pelo seu código isso não será um problema, se acaso for volte a primeira sugestão, criar um a um os elementos e não usar strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função que adiciona esses eventos e chamá-la depois de executar a função que cria os elementos na tela.